# sonarqube ignores postgres and picks embedded database

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I tried to configure sonarqube (7.6) to use postgresql database and it seems to ignore the entries in the sonar.properties and picks up the H2 database. When I pass the properties as jvm parameters, it picks up fine. How do I configure sonar to use postgres from the sonar.properties

sonar.properties:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=myuser
sonar.jdbc.password=mypwd
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://ipaddress:5444/mypostgres
sonar.log.level=DEBUG
```

Log snippet:

```
2019.03.25 05:42:03 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2019.03.25 05:42:03 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 7.6.0.21501 / d56689a5eb122c06cf87375828085609f5a68323
2019.03.25 05:42:03 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2019.03.25 05:42:03 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: /opt/sonarqube/data
2019.03.25 05:42:03 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2019.03.25 05:42:03 WARN  web[][o.s.db.dialect.H2] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only.
2019.03.25 05:42:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
```

Comment: looks like **sonar.log.level=DEBUG** should be defined in the next line. Can be the issue.

Comment: sonar.log.level is defined in a separate line. when I pasted in the SO post, the newline character didn't show up. updated post

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, but where is located your `sonar.properties` file?

Comment: conf/sonar.properties. The properties file is being picked and the logs at 'debug' level are logged.

Comment: @user1573133 have you find t way to not the set the embeded H2 database ?

Comment: @french_dev I passed it as arguments to the command instead of keeping them in properties file